# Performance difference between IOUArray and STUArray (in Prime Sieve)

Tags: performance, haskell

I made a prime sieve in Haskell using mutable arrays. The two main mutable arrays are `IOUArray` and `STUArray` so I checked the performance with both.

On my computer the `IOUArray` runs five times faster than `STUArray` even though the code structure is pretty much the same. Is this expected? Is there something I'm missing to get `STUArray` to run faster?

Edit: I did some profiling, the results can be found below the code.

Here is the code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
module Main where

import Data.Array.MArray
import Data.Array.IO
import Data.Array.ST
import Control.Monad.ST
import Data.Array.Unboxed
import Control.Monad
import System.IO
import System.Environment (getArgs)

main :: IO ()
main = mainIO 
--main = mainST

mainST :: IO ()
mainST = do
  [n',outdir] <- getArgs
  let n      = read n' :: Int
      primes = primeSieveST n
  writeFile outdir (unlines . map show $ primes)
  putStrLn "Primes found using STUArray"

mainIO :: IO ()
mainIO = do
  [n',outdir] <- getArgs
  let n      = read n' :: Int
  primes <- primeSieveIO n
  writeFile outdir (unlines . map show $ primes)
  putStrLn "Primes found using IOUArray"

-- Prime sieve using IOUArray
primeSieveIO :: Int -> IO [Int]
primeSieveIO n = do
  arr <- newArray (1,n) True :: IO (IOUArray Int Bool)
  writeArray arr 1 False
  let p=2
  forM_ [p..n] $ \a -> do
      v <- readArray arr a
      if v then markOff arr a n
           else return ()
  iarr <- freeze arr :: IO (UArray Int Bool)
  return . map fst . filter (\(_,a)-> a) $ assocs iarr

-- Prime sieve using STUArray
primeSieveST :: Int -> [Int]
primeSieveST n = map fst . filter (\(_,a) -> a) . assocs $ runSTUArray $ do
  arr <- newArray (1,n) True
  writeArray arr 1 False
  let p = 2
  forM_ [p..n] $ \a -> do
      v <- readArray arr a
      if v then markOff arr a n 
           else return ()
  return arr


markOff :: (Integral i,Ix i, MArray a Bool m)  => a i Bool -> i -> i -> m ()
markOff arr a n = do
  forM_ [2*a,2*a+a..n] $ \b -> writeArray arr b False
```

I profiled the code (the program is managed by stack, in case it matters), here are the key differences from the `.prof` files:

Using the `IOUArray`:

```
COST CENTRE    MODULE SRC                          %time %alloc

markOff        Main   app/Main.hs:(60,1)-(61,53)    64.1   55.5
primeSieveIO   Main   app/Main.hs:(35,1)-(44,54)    25.2   34.7
mainIO         Main   app/Main.hs:(26,1)-(31,40)     5.9    9.8
markOff.\      Main   app/Main.hs:61:32-53           3.6    0.0
primeSieveIO.\ Main   app/Main.hs:(39,24)-(42,33)    1.3    0.0
```

Using the `STUArray`:

```
COST CENTRE  MODULE    SRC                         %time %alloc

markOff.\    Main      app/Main.hs:61:32-53         63.1   51.9
markOff      Main      app/Main.hs:(60,1)-(61,53)   26.7   33.7
primeSieveST Main      app/Main.hs:(48,1)-(56,12)    7.5   10.9
mainST       Main      app/Main.hs:(18,1)-(23,40)    1.8    2.9
```

So for some reason, the writing function is taking much longer for the STUArray. This program was built and run using stack on OSX. The function on line 61:32-53 is the `writeArray` function.

Comment: ST monad is eventually immutable computation as far as I know. In this context it'll be natural.

Comment: The `ST` version should definitely be faster for, because `runSTUArray` uses [`unsafeFreezeArray#`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim-0.5.0.0/docs/GHC-Prim.html#v:unsafeFreezeArray-35-) internally, whereas your `IO` version (unnecessarily) uses the copying version, [`freezeArray#`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim-0.5.0.0/docs/GHC-Prim.html#v:freezeArray-35-). By the way, some work in progress in GHC could lead to `ST` operations being optimized a bit better in general, and to some `IO` operations slowing down a bit (to get better behavior). So stick with `ST`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what is skewing your measurements, but with [`criterion`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion-1.1.4.0) replacing your `main` with the following

```
import Criterion
import Criterion.Main

main = do
  n <- readLn
  defaultMain
    [ bench "io"  $ nfIO (primeSieveIO n)
    , bench "st"  $ nf primeSieveST n
    ]
```

No matter what input `n` I enter (`criterion` does some funky stuff with arguments which is why `n` is read from STDIN), the `ST` version is about 25% faster. Here is one interaction:

```
$ ./test
100000
benchmarking io
time                 201.2 ms   (140.3 ms .. 280.0 ms)
                     0.943 R²   (0.797 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 214.3 ms   (196.2 ms .. 237.6 ms)
std dev              26.22 ms   (14.72 ms .. 32.72 ms)
variance introduced by outliers: 31% (moderately inflated)

benchmarking st
time                 141.9 ms   (139.8 ms .. 143.5 ms)
                     1.000 R²   (0.999 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 141.0 ms   (140.4 ms .. 141.6 ms)
std dev              815.1 μs   (476.3 μs .. 1.139 ms)
variance introduced by outliers: 12% (moderately inflated)
```

When I factor in file writes, the `IO` version is much *slower*. Are you compiling this or running in GHCi? If the latter, try compiling.

Comment: Uhm... are `nf` and `nfIO` evaluating the whole `[Int]` list? Isn't this comparing only how much time it takes for the first element? (And if so, does that really matter?)

Comment: @chi `nf` stands for normal form (as opposed to `wnhf`), so I expect this is for the whole list.

Comment: @Alec, I'm compiling and executing with stack. I just did some profiling, the results are added to my original post. I will try the `criterion` benchmarking later.

Answer (score 1):

**Edited** to add more detail and a better workaround.

I'm able to duplicate the issue with Stack lts-8.5, compiling with `-O3`.

After looking at the resulting GHC core, it looks like in the IO case, the compiler is able to generate a specialized version of `markOff` that inlines the array writes (literally inlining the setting of the bits in the bit array) into the loop.  For the ST case, it uses a general version of `markOff` instead, and every write goes through an `unsafeWrite` polymorphic call dispatched on the exact `MArray` type which is much, much slower.

If you add a copy of `markOff` named `markOffST` with a signature specialized to `STUArray`s:

```
markOffST :: (Integral i,Ix i) => STUArray s i Bool -> i -> i -> ST s ()
markOffST arr a n = do
  forM_ [2*a,2*a+a..n] $ \b -> writeArray arr b False
```

and then use it in `primeSieveST`, the compiler generates the above specialization for `markOffST` with inlined writes, and you'll find that the ST version is as fast as the IO version (at least when compiling with `-O3`).

It's hard to say if this is a compiler "bug" or not.  GHC just isn't quite making the leap of generating a specialized version of `markOff` in the ST case without a little help.

A workaround without changing signatures is to ask GHC to inline the `markOff` function:

```
{-# INLINE markOff #-}
markOff :: ...
```

which permits the specialized loop code to be generated in both `primeSieveIO` and `primeSieveST`.

Comment: Yes, this seems to work. Is this a bug in `ghc`? It cannot optimize properly when the type signature is too general.

Comment: I added a little more detail to my answer.  I'm not sure that it's a bug, per se.  An optimized version of `markOff` can only be generated for a more specialized type signature than the general one given; it's just that for the IO case, GHC goes ahead and generates an extra, specialized definition that it doesn't generate for the ST version.